# Azure AAD B2C HTTP Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c

*Context*

I have created an AAD B2C Tenant, added a user to that tenant, and registered an application in that tenant.  Locally, I also have an HTML page, and with input fields for username and password, linked to a JS file for sending the post request.

*Question*

**I want to send a post request (ultimately with JS) to attempt to authenticate the user with the username and password provided, and get the JWT bearer token back from AAD B2C for that user if a user with that username and password exists in the AAD B2C Tenant.**

**I am unsure of the URL the request should be sent to, what parameters it should have other than username and password, or the representation of those parameters, for example x-www-url-formencoded, raw JSON body, query string params, etc.**

I don't want to use any redirects, or leverage any libraries at first.

*What I've Tried*

I have done a lot of digging in Microsoft documentation but have yet to find the solution to this.. it should be very easy which makes me wonder if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those looking, this cannot be done with AAD B2C, however it can be done with AAD. See the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc. However this flow is NOT RECOMMENDED unless it is the only flow for your use case. This does seem odd because this use case does not seem rare.

Comment: ^ The comment above is incorrect. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga for Azure AD B2C ROPC flows (ROPC is what I'm trying to describe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already found by yourself all the information needed for your purpose is available at [Configure the resource owner password credentials flow in Azure AD B2C.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga) However to leverage all the security and UX features that Azure B2C can offer I would recommend taking a look to [Use Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript to work with Azure AD B2C.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview)